# In Eclipse, how to run a java program as if it's the second argument in the command prompt while running another program as the first argument?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, run-configuration

This is what I am trying to do. I have been running a 'driver' executable file as the first argument and a java executable file called 'agent' as the second argument in the command prompt / terminal like this:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ./driver agent
```

And each time it works perfectly fine. And I cannot reverse them in order if I do they won't work.

Yet each time if I were to test them I have to recompile my agent.java file to make it an executable and then run it from the command prompt, which is a lot of work.

Is there anyway that I can do this in Eclipse, where I can set Eclipse to run the driver executable file (Not a java executable file, but just an external file) as the first argument like in the command prompt and run the agent.java file as the second argument in the IDE itself as I click the 'Run' button in Eclipse?

My OS is Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations" to define an external tool of the type "Program", supplying the driver as the program name and your Java class as the argument. You'll probably want to check "Build before launch" under "Build". However, you won't be able to do debugging.

Comment: Hi Aasmund Eldhuset, 

so what should I fill in under the Location field after I do a New_configuration after clicking the "Program"? Is it just the name of my file or the whole path of my file? And the Working Directory is? As for the Arguments field, do I just type my Java .class file name as the argument?

Comment: Debugging could be possible if you can pass additional arguments to your java executable. If you can, you can follow http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html to attach to the running java process and start debugging. (Note that you need to do the steps like configuring the remote debug configuration in addition to the *Run -> External Tools* steps described above).

Comment: Did that, setting the agent.class as the argument and the IDE found it but it gives this error: couldn't execute "./agent.class": permission denied

Comment: It only works if the argument passed into the argument field is a executable file. I have tried to pass in .java, .class, .jar in various ways including using .bat and .sh to run the .jar but still failed. Any additional suggestions? Already checked "Build before launch".

Comment: Odd - the arguments aren't supposed to be executed by Eclipse. However, the arguments are relative to the "Working Directory", which you'd need to set equal to the folder that contains the `agent` file. If `./driver agent` works in the command line, then using `/some/path/driver` as the "Location", `/some/path` as "Working Directory" and `agent` as "Arguments" should work.

Comment: So that means the agent has to be an executable like agent.exe, but not the agent.class file since Eclipse cannot execute .class file as the argument that way right?

Comment: The arguments are just strings that are passed to the executable, just as when you're running a command in the terminal. The only thing that needs to be executable is the "Location". Just make sure that `driver` and `agent` exist in some folder so that running `./driver agent` in the command line works, and specify `/home/pythonview/driver` (or whatever the correct folder name is) as "Location", `/home/pythonview` as "Working Directory", and `agent` as the parameter. This should have the same effect as running `./driver agent` in a command line.

Comment: What if I want to run the agent.java file together with the driver? Since I would like to test my agent.java file right after I make changes to my code in the agent.java.

Since compiling it again and make it a agent.jar file then use Java wrapper software to make it agent.exe will take quite sometime after I make changes to my code in agent.java.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. What does this driver program do? You're aware that `./driver agent` only launches `driver`, and sends the _string_ `agent` as an argument to the driver? If what the driver does is to invoke the program whose name it receives as an argument, then well, you need to give it a program as an argument. If you want `./driver agent.java` to actually execute the program in `agent.java`, you need to rewrite the driver and have the driver compile and run the Java code (or make it a Java interpreter, which will be a lot of work...)

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that the driver got launched and the agent is passed into the driver as an argument. What I am trying to do now is when I hit run, I want the agent.java to be automatically compiled and run by Eclipse as well and immediately get passed into the driver which is launched ( at the same time when i hit run on the Eclipse IDE ). The reason is because I am developing code for the agent.java in Eclipse, and the driver is already fixed and won't be changed. I need to always test run the code in agent.java multiple times as I am developing it.

Comment: So you want to run the agent through eclipse? What does the driver do with the agent, then?